# Cannot get project to build with new framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I'm working on an old project which has had a new framework added since my older copy. I've added the project by dragging it to the Framework folder but when I build I get an error saying it is missing one of the headers.

[image]

The WGFramework is listed along with the header files, including WGLog.h which is supposed to be missing

[image]

It is also listed in the Link Binary With Libraries in Build Phases. What do I need to do to get my project to recognise this framework that is clearly listed?

Comment: Is it happening with the other header files from this framework, or is it specific to one header only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking the framework search path?

> *Project -> Build Settings -> "Frameworks Search Path" field*

Make sure it points to where the headers are located (or at least a parent directory with the recursive option).

In the command line:

> find . -type f -iname "*WGLog.h"